# Remove junk from a file

Tags: sed, grep

I have a csv file with some junk at the beginning of the file. How do I get rid of it?

```
sh-3.2# more data_combined.csv
ï»¿84252,1,A ROSEAL
```

The file should start with the number 842...

Comment: I think this is a unicode BOM signature. you can have the CSV generating software export the file in ASCII encoding instead of unicode.

Comment: @Salman A: Regarded as UTF-8, I think those 3 characters are 0xC3 0xAF 0xC2 0xBB 0xC2 0xBF (at least, on an Intel Mac - little-endian; I don't think it matters).  The [Unicode FAQ on BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) says that the UTF-8 encoding of the BOM (U+FEFF) is 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF.  I don't think there's a way to get the bytes shown as an encoding of a BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data shown, this should do the trick (assuming a single-byte codeset such as ISO 8859-1, and not UTF-8, for example):

```
sed '1s/^...//' data_combined.csv
```

If it is UTF-8, then there are 6 bytes of garbage at the start.  If `sed` is run with a UTF-8 locale, the '`.`' metacharacter matches a UTF-8 character (2 bytes each in the case shown), so the same expression works fine.  If `sed` is run with a SBCS (single-byte code set) such as 8859-1, then you'd need to use a pattern like:

```
sed '1s/^.\{6\}//' data_combined.csv
```

Actually, it would use as many characters to write 6 dots; but the generalization is perhaps clearer.

---

As [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) correctly said in the all too brief interval while I slept, to remove non-digits from the start of the first line, use:

```
sed '1s/^[^0-9]*//' data_combined.csv
```

Comment: sed '1s/^.//' data_combined.csv ## has solved this problem. Thanks. But I get the file from third party and I do not know if that character will always be there or if there will be more than 1 junk character. But I am sure that I want to start from a digit. (in this case 8) Is there any way?

Comment: @shantanuo: To delete all non-digit characters from the beginning of line 1 (do nothing if there are none): `sed '1s/^[^0-9]*//' data_combined.csv`